# How can I make an Aranea player character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, monsters

What would an Aranea player character look like? What'd its stats be, and how many racial HD would it have?
Does it being a 'magical beast' have any effects?

The creature has been given an LA, so it seems like it should be playable. However, no rules about Aranea as Player Characters have been given for as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Are you looking for the mechanics for sucha character or how to properly role-play such a character?

Comment: I am looking for the mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Aranea monster](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/aranea.htm):

- Bonus Feat: Iron Will.
- +2 racial bonus on Jump, Listen, and Spot checks. They have a +8 racial bonus on Climb checks and can always choose to take 10 on Climb checks even if rushed or threatened.
- Class skills:

  - Climb
  - Concentration
  - Escape Artist
  - Jump
  - Listen
  - Spot

#### Magical Beast type:

- BAB as fighter (+1 per level)
- Good Fortitude and Reflex saves
- Skillpoints (2+int)
- Darkvision out to 60 feet and low-light vision.
- Proficient with its natural weapons.
- Proficient with no armor.
- Magical beasts eat, sleep, and breathe.

#### Shapechanger Subtype:

- Proficiency with all simple weapons
- When affected by a spell of the [polymorph subschool](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060501a&page=5), is able to change back as an action:

> A creature with the shapechanger subtype (such as a lycanthrope or doppelganger) can revert to its natural form as a standard action.

#### **(Savage Species page 154)** Aranea Class / Level progression (

1. First hit die; +2 cha, +2 dex, bite 1d4, poison (1d3 str, 1d3 str), alternate form (hybrid 3/day, 1 hour), speed 30ft / climb 25ft
2. Second hit die; Sorcerer level 1, +2 cha, +2 int, +1 natural armor
3. Bite 1d6, alternate form (hybrid at will), +2 dex, +2 con
4. Sorcerer level 2, poison (1d6 str, 1d6 str), speed 40 feet, +2 int
5. Web 3/day, alternate form (humanoid 3/day, 1 hour), +2 wis
6. Third hit die; Sorcerer level 3, poison (2d6 str, 2d6 str), +2 con
7. Web 6/day, alternate form (humanoid at will), speed 50 feet
8. & onwards, **By character class.**

Counts as a 3rd level sorcerer for spellcasting purposes only. Leveling as sorcerer (or PRC that add +level spellcasting) advances the spellcasting progression accordingly. Does not have a familiar unless gained through class advancement (i.e. takes 1 level of sorcerer, wizard or the feat "Acquire Familiar")

---

If the DM agrees to use the [ECL reduction optional rule](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/reducingLevelAdjustments.htm), the aranea can **immediately after** reaching character level 19 (12 class levels beyond the monster progression) pay 18,000xp and reduce the ECL by 1 (becoming a level 18 character, 3 monster HD, 12 class levels and +3 ECL)

Comment: This would be bolstered by citations to show how and why this is the case, at the very least to show this external resource is accurate and not homebrew. "Here is a thing generated by a site" can be a useful thing to do, but shouldn't be the entirety of an answer. It helps to teach people how to fish, not just give them a single fish, since that equips people to figure things out for themselves later with other monster types & even if the site goes offline.

Comment: @doppelgreener i took it from the site, but actually it is on page 154 of the book. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 8):

The SRD entry on [monsters as races](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monstersAsRaces.htm) should have everything you need.

The short version is that an [Aranea](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/aranea.htm) has 3 racial hit dice and +4 level adjustment, so you'd need to be level 7 to start as one<sup>*</sup>.

Their racial bonuses to stats are: +0 Str, +4 Dex, +4 Con, +4 Int, +2 Wis, +4 Cha.

They get 2 feats from their Magical Beast hit dice, plus Iron Will as a bonus feat. Note that, as you gain levels, you gain ability points and feats based on hit dice, not ECL, so you'd gain an ability point the next time you level (and, thus, have 4 HD, one of which is in a class) and a feat along with your 3rd class level (at 6 HD).

<sup>* NOTE: Savage Species is a 3.0 book with guidelines for converting monsters into "classes", so you could start as an "Aranea" at level 1,
 and level up with the party. They're ... of mixed success in my experience.</sup>